# Iterating over nested array , the es6 way, I have already done using foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have done the iteration using forEach ,code is working but please could you suggest if it can be done in es6 way and is my implementation correct or not

I have done the iteration , the code works ,however I wanted to know more sleek way of doing it and whether this implementation is correct

```
  var arrayToBeChecked = 
          [
            { name: "one",
              objectvalue : {
                        first : ['valueIamNotInterestedIn0'],
                        second :'valueIamNotInterestedIn1'
                       }
             },
             { name: "two",
               objectvalue : {
                        first : ['valueIamLookingFor'],
                        second :'valueIamNotInterestedIn5'
                       }
             },
             { name: "three",
               objectvalue : {
                        first : ['valueIamNotInterestedIn5'],
                        second :'valueIamNotInterestedIn5'
                       }
             }

          ]

   var checkBoolean = false;

   arrayToBeChecked.forEach(val => {
    let selectedArray =  val.objectvalue['first']
      if(selectedArray.indexOf('valueIamLookingFor') > -1){
         checkBoolean = true 
      }
   })

   console.log(checkBoolean)
```

Comment: If the value you were looking for was actually in the `valueIamNotInterestedIn5` place (and not in the original place), would you want a match?

Comment: Yeah my goal is to only check for 'valueIamLookingFor' in first(array) irrespective of the object index

Comment: So `objectvalue.second` shouldn't be checked?

Comment: @HarijsDeksnis , any of the objectvalue but definitely within first(array) i'll be checking

Comment: Then I think my answer should work for you. It checks both first and second.
Or do you also want it will check any other property besides those two?

Comment: @HarijsDeksnis , in my current impl I am expecting in first(array) , but ur answer also looks good.

Comment: @HarijsDeksnis are u using destructuring

Comment: Yes, destructuring and picking out only `objectvalue` property per every `.map` iteration

Comment: but why we have to map if directly we are using some

Comment: You don't have to. I just use it for convenience. Then the calls are shorter, simpler and easier to read, in my opinion.

Comment: @HarijsDeksnis ok .Thankyou very much :)

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for the upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach is not that efficient because you'll keep iterating even after you find a match. For this kind of check (see if any of the values of the array match a condition) you can use [`.some(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Here is an example:

```js
var arrayToBeChecked = [{
    name: "one",
    objectvalue: {
      first: ['valueIamNotInterestedIn0'],
      second: 'valueIamNotInterestedIn1'
    }
  },
  {
    name: "two",
    objectvalue: {
      first: ['valueIamLookingFor'],
      second: 'valueIamNotInterestedIn5'
    }
  },
  {
    name: "three",
    objectvalue: {
      first: ['valueIamNotInterestedIn5'],
      second: 'valueIamNotInterestedIn5'
    }
  }

];

const result = arrayToBeChecked.some(({
  objectvalue: {
    first
  }
}) => first.includes('valueIamLookingFor'));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 way would be first to map the array to the values you are only interested in.
And then using `some` Array method to find if any of the items pass your criteria.

Also, instead of `indexOf` you can use `includes` which returns a boolean.

```
  const checkBoolean = arrayToBeChecked
    .map(({ objectvalue }) => [...objectvalue.first, objectvalue.second ])
    .some(v => v.includes('valueIamLookingFor'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for getting `first` in combination with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which exits the loop on a truthy return value and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for checking the value.

```js
var arrayToBeChecked = [{ name: "one", objectvalue: { first: ['valueIamNotInterestedIn0'], second: 'valueIamNotInterestedIn1' } }, { name: "two", objectvalue: { first: ['valueIamLookingFor'], second: 'valueIamNotInterestedIn5' } }, { name: "three", objectvalue: { first: ['valueIamNotInterestedIn5'], second: 'valueIamNotInterestedIn5' } }],
    checkBoolean = arrayToBeChecked
        .some(({ objectvalue: { first } }) => first.includes('valueIamLookingFor'));

console.log(checkBoolean);
```

Comment: One question I have , why array.find hasn't been used.Please explain.Thanks

Comment: you want a boolean value, not the object where the first value is found.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to map to the `Object.values` of each item, flatten the array, then check to see if it `.includes` what you're looking for:

```js
var arrayToBeChecked = [{
    name: "one",
    objectvalue: {
      first: ['valueIamNotInterestedIn0'],
      second: 'valueIamNotInterestedIn1'
    }
  },
  {
    name: "two",
    objectvalue: {
      first: ['valueIamLookingFor'],
      second: 'valueIamNotInterestedIn5'
    }
  },
  {
    name: "three",
    objectvalue: {
      first: ['valueIamNotInterestedIn5'],
      second: 'valueIamNotInterestedIn5'
    }
  }

]

const checkBoolean = arrayToBeChecked
  .map(({ objectvalue }) => Object.values(objectvalue))
  .flat(2)
  .includes('valueIamLookingFor');
console.log(checkBoolean)
```

Comment: So is using 'some' or the approach u r telling is correct , or are both correct

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [**some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of forEach, as you're making `checkBoolean` to true if any of the element matches

```js
var arrayToBeChecked = [{name: "one",objectvalue: {first: ['valueIamNotInterestedIn0'],second: 'valueIamNotInterestedIn1'}},{name: "two",objectvalue: {first: ['valueIamLookingFor'],second: 'valueIamNotInterestedIn5'}},{name: "three",objectvalue: {first: ['valueIamNotInterestedIn5'],second: 'valueIamNotInterestedIn5'}}]

var checkBoolean =
  arrayToBeChecked.some(val => {
    let selectedArray = val.objectvalue['first']
    return selectedArray && selectedArray.indexOf('valueIamLookingFor') > -1
})

console.log(checkBoolean)
```